# MySQL key name of data array fetched with UNION

Tags: mysql, union

The table `objects`

```
id    name    is_animal
-----------------------
1     dog     1
2     cat     1
3     chair   0
4     rabbit  1
```

The query

```
(SELECT name AS animal_name FROM objects WHERE is_animal = 1)
UNION
(SELECT name AS object_name FROM objects WHERE is_animal = 0)
```

and the result

```
[animal_name] => dog
[animal_name] => cat
[animal_name] => rabbit
[animal_name] => chair    // expected: [object_name] => chair
```

I've already used `AS` in the second SELECT, why does it return `animal_name` instead of `object_name`?

Comment: Do you want two different fields (animal_name/object_name) ?

Comment: @Grisha yes, chair should have a key name `object_name` and others with `animal_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `UNION` :

```
(SELECT name AS animal_name,'' object_name FROM objects WHERE is_animal = 1)
UNION
(SELECT '' as animal_name, name AS object_name FROM objects WHERE is_animal = 0)
```

with `case` :

```
select case is_animal when 1 name else '' end as  animal_name,
       case is_animal when 0 name else '' end as  object_name
from objects
```

Answer (score 0):

In UNION queries always the column name of the first SELECT is chosen as the column names of the final resultant view. How do you expect the column names to be in the end if corresponding column names of each individual SELECTs are different? It's appropriate to not even mention the column names in subsequent SELECTs in UNION queries because it adds no meaning.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) MySQL uses the same

```
(SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
UNION
(SELECT 2, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col, col1a;
```

Comment: never knew that `always the column name of the first SELECT is chosen as the column names`. thanks for the info, nawfal.